# Updating a class with readonly properties in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, properties

What is a good pattern for creating and updating a class with readonly properties? An example for such a class

```
@interface ReadOnlyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSUInteger number;

@end
```

It is not necessary for the class user to call the `init` constructor (although this is not really possible to avoid in Objective-C) or anything else. Apple uses this pattern e.g. in [CMLogItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMLogItem_Class/index.html) or [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/coordinate). So, how can I change/update the value of `number` in a good manner?

Comment: What do you mean by "updating"? Changing values during runtime? Adding fields to your API?

Comment: In the given example, I want to update the number. But not on user level, but on internal calculations - just as `CMLogItem` is not changeable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best pattern matching for what ask is the Builder Pattern.

EG : You have your read only property which is the result, then some function calculate. You can set various parameters inside like

```
-(void) setMathExpression:(NSString) aExpression;
-(void) calculate;
```

Then the user can set an expression, call calculate then get the result from the readonly property.

Comment: Yes, it is probably the builder pattern, but as far as I know, I would need a public builder property. But it seems that this does not hold for the `CLLocation` and `CMLogItem`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, `number` is a computed property or – to have a better term – depending property. The value of `number` depends on other properties that can change themselves. Correct?

Usually you simply write an explicit setter for this:

```
-(NSUInteger)number
{
  return /* your calculation */;
}
```

For example:  You have another property `playerName` and you want to return the number of characters. (Okay, not very exiting, but I need an example.)

```
-(NSUInteger)number
{
  return [self.playerName length];
}
```

Please note: Since you overwrite all methods declared for the read-only property, no ivar is synthesized.

If the calculation is expensive or the getter is executed more often than the setters for the changeable properties (`playerName`) by far, it can be an optimization to change the property inside the class into a read-write property and set the value, every time the changeable properties are changed.

```
@interface ReadOnlyClass ()
@property (readwrite, …) NSUInteger number;
…
@end

// number is synthesized in this case
-(void)setPlayerName:(NSString*)playerName
{
   _playerName  = playerName;
   self.number = [playerName length];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, but no, this is not what I am looking for, because the class shall have not a single `readwrite` method - there shall be no way from outside to change the value, just as the mentioned examples 'CMLogItem' or 'CLLocation'.